# Selecting attribute value with PHP's xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I'm new to xpath and am running into troubles with PHP's ancient XPath implementation. Is it correct, that `//@url` is just the abbreviated form of `//attribute::url`? I'm trying to query the flickr rss for testing, but the abbreviated query finds the correct nodes, whereas the verbose one returns 0 elements:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?format=rss_200');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->query('//media:content/@url')->length > 0;
$xpath->query('//media:content/attribute::url')->length == 0;
```

Did I misunderstand the [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#location-paths) or is this a PHP bug?

Related question:

The successful query returns [`DOMAttr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php) objects as expected. But is there no way to get the text value of these nodes directly? Something like `//media:content/attribute::url/child::text()`? I would need that for a tool where the xpath queries will be entered by users and the error detection would be much better if I could expect DOMText objects (instead of coding for a multitude of DOM* objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you probably landed on a bug there. It looks 100% fine to me.

as to your related question, use [evaluate][1] instead of query to get php to try to return a typed result. if it fails, it returns the normal nodelist

Edit:

Have you tried adding a [namespace][2]? the media: part might be throwing it for a loop.
e.g.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('media', "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
```

Edit 2:
just for reference, I also tried this in javascript using the following

```
function nsResolve() {
    return "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
}

document.evaluate("//media:content/attribute::url",document,nsResolve,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
```

and it works the same as using @url (currently 7 results)
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php
[2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php

Comment: Thx, but using evaluate() didn't help. I tried adding the namespace, too - no success. I don't know for sure, but I think the namespaces are extracted out of the document by PHP, anyway.

Comment: in that case, go with the abbreviated form. I tend to prefer the verbose format in many cases (descendant-or-self for example) but I can't say I've tried to use the verbose attribute:: axis

Answer (score 0):

Does `//*@url` work?